# Understand group extensions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I will try to explain what I know so far (not certain is it right though):

> A group extension is denoted by $G = N.Q$ or $N:Q$ (the second case is a semidirect product) I think this just means $G/N \unlhd Q$. but it is not fully specified by this, you also have to give an action of $Q$ on $N$.

now what I want to ask is what are the basic important facts that are useful to know about $G$ we can deduce from knowing about $N$ and $Q$ but not knowing the action?

Comment: If we know the action is fixed point free, but nothing more than that, then $G=N:Q$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $N$ and complement $Q$, and we've got that $N$ is nilpotent and each Sylow subgroup of $Q$ are either cyclic or generalized quaternion.  There is in general more than one possible fixed point free automorphism to pick for the semidirect product, so we don't need to know the exact action here.

Comment: Where can I learn more about group extensions?

Comment: I'd start with a finite group theory book (I like Isaacs) since finite group extensions are currently a little better understood.  Also [here](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/GroupExtensions.pdf) is a neat little survey article about them.  Group extensions are a pretty broad topic, though.  Is there anything in particular you want to know about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In finite group theory, we can get a basic important fact without knowing the action: Order.
$$ \lvert G \rvert = \lvert G/N \rvert \lvert N \rvert = \lvert Q \rvert \lvert N \rvert. $$

And subgroups of $N$ and $Q$ are embedded into $G$, so we know its subgroups structure a little.